# Linux bash script that pings multiple IP addresses from a file

Tags: linux, bash

I have a file containing multiple hosts and IPs in the format above:

```
alpha, 192.168.1.1
beta,  192.168.1.2
gamma, 192.168.1.3
```

I am trying to create a script that says something like:

"Pinging hostname alpha"

```
ping 192.168.1.1
```

and jump to the next ip in the list.
I don't want the entire script, just some suggestions.

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: The format is all on one line?

Comment: no, each row contains one record, delimited by a comma

Comment: Look up the `read` command. `while read -a words`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add a comma to the input field separator, it'll help parse the lines:

```
IFS=$IFS,
while read name ip; do
    echo -n "Pinging hostname $name..."
    ping -c2 "$ip" &>/dev/null && echo success || echo fail
done < /tmp/hosts
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd read in the lines with `read`. You'll probably also want to give `ping` an option telling it how many times to ping. The default on most Linux systems for example is to ping forever, which doesn't seem like it would work well in your situation.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [AWK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK):

```
$ awk '{print "Pinging hostname "$1; system("ping -c 3 "$2) }' ips
Pinging hostname alpha,
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

You can also remove that comma if is it important to you:

```
$ awk '{sub(/,/,"");print "Pinging hostname "$1; system("ping -c 3 "$2) }' ips
Pinging hostname alpha
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be a bit late to the party, but how about [fping](http://linux.die.net/man/8/fping)? Use -f to read from a file (requires sudo), or pipe the file with < (as suggested on the man page). It won't tell you "pinging alpha", but it will quickly tell you whether or not you can get in touch with the hosts.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I know this is possible using fping, but i needed to create a script for learning purposes. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

##### Script for hosting 100+ hosts in same scheme like 192.168.xx.xxx

```
 #!/bin/bash
    for i in `seq ${2} ${3}`
    do
        ping -c 1 ${1}.${i} > /dev/null 2>&1
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
            echo "${1}.${i} responded."
        else
            echo "${1}.${i} did not respond."
        fi
    done
```

command to ping the host

`bash test.sh 192.168.1 0 100`

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
#!/bin/bash
IPLIST="path_to_the_Ip_list_file"


for ip in $(cat $IPLIST)

do
    ping $ip -c 1 -t 1 &> /dev/null
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then

        echo $ip ping faild;

        else

        echo $ip ping passed;

    fi

done
```

Comment: Does not really parse the second field.

Comment: @Renjith check what are you pinging `$ for ip in $(cat ips);do echo $ip;done`